# Как сделать запрос на разрешения уведомлений на сайте?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Я новичек в сайтостроении у меня есть главная страница index.html как мне сделать чтобы при входе на сайт сразу появлялся полупрозрачный фон и запрос на разрешение уведомления чтобы продолжить, если пользователь нажал блокировать появлялся надпись ошибка вы нажали блокировать и переспрашивал разрешение? На чём это сделать на php, javascript?

Comment: Какой ужас, я бы с такого сайта сразу сбежал бы. Где меня принуждают совершить действие. Походит на вирус-вымогатель

Comment: ну жили же как то без этих уведомлений в браузере и все было ок. А сейчас домашние страницы котиков просят рассылать уведомления (я читаю это так - "я буду отправлять рекламу, спам и мусор, давай соглашайся"

Comment: @KoVadim хромиумы умеют рубить сиё дерьмо на всех сайтах сразу, гдет в настройках включается..

Comment: я знаю, у меня по умолчанию зарублено. и я думаю, оно так и должно быть, ну может маленький список белых сайтов. А ещё желательно блочить всякую "фоновую работу".

Answer (score 0):

Вам следует использовать библиотеку Push.js

Пример кода:

```
Push.create("Hello world!", {
    body: "How's it hangin'?",
    icon: '/icon.png',
    timeout: 4000,
    onClick: function () {
        window.focus();
        this.close();
    }
});
```

В коде выше, если нет разрешения на уведомления, то push.js автоматически его запросит. Не стоит заставлять юзера принимать ваши уведомления, если он не хочет, значить он не хочет.

[Документация Push.js](https://pushjs.org/)